# Jenkins job triggered by Git Action building incorrect branch

Tags: git, jenkins, github

We have a Jenkins job that is triggered by a [Github Action](https://github.com/appleboy/jenkins-action) (listed below).

```
name: CI


on:
  pull_request:
    branches: 
      - test/*
    types: [ closed ]

jobs:
  build:
    if: github.event.pull_request.merged == true
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: trigger single Job
      uses: appleboy/jenkins-action@master
      with:
        url: "https://example.company.com"
        user: "appleboy"
        token: ${{ secrets.TOKEN }}
        job: "Pipeline"
```

The trigger is wildcarded right now to be any branch that begins with `test/`. Everytime the trigger fires, however, the Jenkins job pulls & builds from the wrong branch. What I've noticed is that everytime this happens, I need to hard code the branch in the Jenkins UI and select the "Build Now" option and run it manually. When I return the build to the wildcard spec and the trigger fires again, this time from a new branch, it builds from the branch I had previously manually entered. Example workflow:

1. PR is merged into branch `test/v1`
2. Jenkins job is triggerd but builds from the branch previously entered manually (i.e. `test/v0`)
3. I hard code the branch and manually execute the build

[image]

4. Return the pipeline to the wildcard configuration

[image]

5. PR is merged into branch `test/v2`
6. Jenkins job is triggered but builds from `test/v1` branch

**UPDATE**

By removing the `remotes` from the branch specifier I get the following behavior:

1. PR is merged into `test/v2`
2. Jenkins job is triggerd but builds from `test/v1`
3. Another job is triggered at the same time that builds from `test/v2`

[image]

Looking in the logs for the build from step 2 I see the following message (this is not present in the build from step 3):

> Multiple candidate revisions
>
> Scheduling another build to catch up with Pipeline

Answer (score 2):

This turned out to be the issue mentioned in the link below. There were multiple branches in the repo that began with `origin/test/`, causing multiple build candidates. Simply deleting those branches solved the issue.

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-21464?focusedCommentId=250183&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-250183